# Handling POST data in django forms

Tags: django, forms, post

What is the difference (if any) between the following 2 approaches when handling POST data in a form view:

1.

```
def form_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # handle POST data here
```

2.

```
 def form_view(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
         form = MyForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             # handle POST data here
     else:
         form = MyForm()
```

Comment: Either way, if you're working with form's then you would be better off using [django's Editing Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#generic-editing-views) which makes this question mute.

Comment: @sayse class based views aren't automatically better than function based views. Even if you choose to use cbvs everywhere, you are still likely to come across the `request.POST or None` trick in other people's code, so it's useful to understand why it works.

Comment: @Alasdair - I agree its helpful to understand how they work. CBV's (in my opinion) come into their own when you start needing to start your views with the line "if method = x" (or post or none), separation of logic makes for cleaner code and CBVs stop forbidden http requests automagically etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `request.POST or None` is a shortcut, which is used to make the view shorter (although it makes it harder to understand if you haven't seen the technique before). It's useful to be familiar with this trick, because you'll come across it in other people's code. Most of the time, views will work the same whichever approach you take. However, there there are some edge cases, so the safest approach would be to avoid the trick.

The trick works because `request.POST` is an empty dict for GET requests. That means that:

- `request.POST or None` is equivalent to `{} or None` for get requests, which evaluates to None.
- `request.POST or None` evaluates to `request.POST` for post requests, as long as the post request is not empty.

Therefore, you can use `MyForm(request.POST or None)`, instead of having to include the if statement and instantiate the form in both branches.

The edge cases occur for post requests when `request.POST` is empty. This is unusual, but can occur, for example if a form contains only checkboxes, and you submit it with none selected.

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST or None` - will pass data to the form if request.POST is not empty(so it is POST request) otherwise it will pass None(and for will act in the same way with `MyForm()`).

If nothing has been passed to from it won't be valid, but not errors will be occured at the same time.

If something will be passed to form but data will be invalid, `is_valid()` will return False as well, but under `form.errors` raised errors will be placed.

Long story short, this way allows you to write code in more short and elegant manner.